# Comparing time or ditching date in ruby on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I have some time defined from my database, and this is how it looks:

```
ruby-1.9.2-p290 :017 > djel.smjena.pocetak1.to_time 
 => 2000-01-01 08:00:00 +0100
```

and that is ok, it assigned me 2000-1-1 
also, I got something that happened in some datetime

```
ruby-1.9.2-p290 :019 > dog.pocetak 
 => Thu, 25 Aug 2011 08:18:00 UTC +00:00
```

So I was hoping, that .to_time would ditch my date, but that does not 
happen

```
ruby-1.9.2-p290 :020 > dog.pocetak.to_time 
 => Thu, 25 Aug 2011 08:18:00 UTC +00:00
```

so, now, comparing if something happened before 8:00 is useless. 
So, how  can I compare that? is there a way to set dog.pocetak to 
2000-01-01 without touch clock?

thank you

p.s. also, I thought of creating new time variable, only to get from old variable hours and minutes, but this methods dont work?

```
ruby-1.9.2-p290 :059 > dog.pocetak.hour
 => 8
```

but

```
ruby-1.9.2-p290 :060 > dog.pocetak.minute
NoMethodError: undefined method `minute' for 2011-08-25 08:18:00 UTC:Time
        from /home/dorijan/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/activesupport-3.0.10/lib/active_support/time_with_zone.rb:322:in `method_missing'
        from (irb):60
        from /home/dorijan/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/railties-3.0.10/lib/rails/commands/console.rb:44:in `start'
        from /home/dorijan/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/railties-3.0.10/lib/rails/commands/console.rb:8:in `start'
        from /home/dorijan/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/railties-3.0.10/lib/rails/commands.rb:23:in `<top (required)>'
        from script/rails:6:in `require'
        from script/rails:6:in `<main>'
ruby-1.9.2-p290 :061 > dog.pocetak.minutes
NoMethodError: undefined method `minutes' for 2011-08-25 08:18:00 UTC:Time
        from /home/dorijan/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/activesupport-3.0.10/lib/active_support/time_with_zone.rb:322:in `method_missing'
        from (irb):61
        from /home/dorijan/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/railties-3.0.10/lib/rails/commands/console.rb:44:in `start'
        from /home/dorijan/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/railties-3.0.10/lib/rails/commands/console.rb:8:in `start'
        from /home/dorijan/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/railties-3.0.10/lib/rails/commands.rb:23:in `<top (required)>'
        from script/rails:6:in `require'
        from script/rails:6:in `<main>'
```

really frustrating :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With `ActiveSupport` and `Time.change` you can reset the year, month and day if you like:

```
> t = Time.now
=> Sun Aug 21 00:46:29 +0000 2011
> t.change(:month => 1, :day => 1, :year => 2000)
=> Sat Jan 01 00:46:29 +0000 2000
```

This way you *could* compare the "times" between each other, if they all were reset to the same date. Not sure if this is a good solution though, depends on what you really are looking for.

**EDIT**:

As per mu's suggestion you could also take a look at the [time](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/time.html) data type.

Comment: Both [PostgreSQL](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.0/interactive/datatype-datetime.html) and [MySQL](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/time.html) have `time` data types, PostgreSQL also has an interval type (MySQL's `time` does double duty for time of day and intervals). I would expect other databases to have similar types (all subtly incompatible though, standards and all that :).

Comment: @mu - Thanks for the clarification mu. How did I miss that..uh. Need more sleep. Edited.

Answer (score 3):

To get the minutes from a Time object, you want [`min`](http://ruby-doc.org/core/classes/Time.html#M000362) not `minutes`. You can't have a Time instance that's just a "time of day" (i.e. no year, month, ...) but you can use `strftime` to get a string version that will compare properly:

```
tod = Time.now.strftime('%H:%M:%S')
# "17:07:23"

if(t1.strftime('%H:%M:%S') == t2.strftime('%H:%M:%S'))
    # Same time of day (to one second resolution)
end
```

Or you could compare the individual [`hour`](http://ruby-doc.org/core/classes/Time.html#M000363), [`min`](http://ruby-doc.org/core/classes/Time.html#M000362), and [`sec`](http://ruby-doc.org/core/classes/Time.html#M000361) components:

```
if(t1.hour == t2.hour && t1.min == t2.min && t1.sec == t2.sec)
    # Same time of day (to one second resolution)
end
```

Which approach you take depends, as usual, on your specific situation and what else is going in in that vicinity.